# Strange behaviour when trying to send transactional emails using AWS Lambda and Mailgun

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, mailgun

**Background:** I've been using Lambda functions to send transactional e-mails using the Mailgun service. I've chosen to implement the server using node.js because I had used this language before but I don't have much experience working on the server side so I've been struggling a little bit to understand what's happening.

**Task:** The ideia is to send a personalised email to multiple recipients registered for this particular message performing just one request to the Lambda function.

**Problem:** To perform the task explained above, I've come up with this basic implementation following the Mailgun docs and API Reference. I used a `forEach` so I could send a custom email to each recipient, which was what I was expecting to achieve.

[image: Node implementation]

When testing locally, everything works just fine. The request is performed and the emails are sent as expected.

However, after deploying the code to AWS a strange behaviour starts to occur. When the request is performed it seems that the execution of the code stops before finishing which results in the delivery of just few emails. Other thing that always happens is that the 1st invocation of the lambda function isn't triggering the `sendBulkTemplatedEmail` but after the first attempt things start to get going.

That's how the logs on CloudWatch look like:

[image]

Each blue line is a request that I performed using postman. For tests purposes, I'm always using 3 recipients for the emails. The red lines represents the `console.log(body)` I've added to my code. When a message like **{ id: '<201910100230..** appears on the log, it means that the email was sent successfully.

**1st request:** none email was sent.

**2nd request:** two emails were sent.

**3rd request:** three emails were sent + the one that should have been sent in the second request.

**4th request:** three emails were sent (expected behaviour)

**5th request:** three emails were sent (expected behaviour)

**6th request:** three emails were sent (expected behaviour)

I don't understand why this is happening when running my code remotely but not happening when running locally. My guess is that these problems are related to the timeout of the lambda functions in some way but I wasn't able to fix it.

Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I've seen behaviour like this when I first started working with JS/lambdas, and was completely new to both so was not implementing asynchronous stuff correctly. Firstly it's difficult to say much because your code above presumably isn't the full lambda, so I can't see how the code above is being used. My suspicion is you're not awaiting the sending of the emails correctly, which allows the lambda to return and say it's complete when there are still unresolved promises. Then (in req 2) the final promise eventually resolves and is logged, so appears to be part of req3 when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your handler code, I am suspecting two possible scenarios:

1. Your handler is using `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false` which cause the lambda to end when you call the `callback` function.
2. Your handler is an async handler and it doesn't return the promise or await the promise.

Looking at the snippet, you also didn't properly return an array of send email promises that your handler can await on. To do this, change your `sendBulkTemplateEmail` function to:

```js
 const sendBulkTemplateEmail = (config) => (group) => {
   return group.participants.map((participant) => {
      //processing code that you have been doing;
      return mailgun.messages().send(data)})
    }
}
```

This way, it return an array of promises that you can await on in your handler:

```js
const handler = async (event) => {
  // event processing
  await Promise.all(sendBulkTemplateEmail(config)(group))
}
```

In newer version of lambda handler, you no longer need to call `callback` to resolve an async lambda.

For reference on lambda handler, you can refer to this doc [AWS Lambda Function Handler in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async):

> The third argument, callback, is a function that you can call in non-async handlers to send a response. The callback function takes two arguments: an Error and a response. When you call it, Lambda waits for the event loop to be empty and then returns the response or error to the invoker. The response object must be compatible with JSON.stringify.

For async handlers, you return a response, error, or promise to the runtime instead of using callback.

Hopefully this help to solve your mystery! (It certainly does for me as I spent few hours try and error and finally got this working by adding an await to my promise.)